# sharepoint website modification and user activity interception

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft365

There are several topics I have questions about, where googling did no good to me, neither did it lead me to any valuable resources.

1. Can I modify the SharePoint page to my needs, like can I customize it so much that I can add something like a 'calculator of services'(like there are dropdowns and depending on different selected ones calculated results change)on it. I saw that I can embed html, but everything I saw and stumbled up-on is kind of abstract.
2. Can I intercept the users who e.g.: click on a button. I have a SharePoint webpage with users within it, if user1 clicked a button can I be informed about that or can I trigger some actions as a result ?
3. Can I have a file upload on SharePoint page ?

Any resource/comment/friendly advice will be valuable for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pages can be modified quite a bit with SharePoint Framework. With SharePoint Framework (SPFx) you could add custom webparts to the page to add your own custom logic. As well you can build extensions that can insert a custom header or footer into the page. If what you are trying to add has logic that requires something like JavaScript I would strongly recommend SPFx
2. Sort of. If its your own custom logic, not an issue. If its OOTB logic, it gets problematic as you need to target that custom component and add your own events to try to override the behavior. However this is often a bad practice as things always are changing. Your target selector may break on any update, and at this point anyway its more of a hack trying to integrate with other private logic.
3. Yes this is completely [doable with SPFx](https://ravichandran.blog/2020/05/04/file-browse-and-select-or-upload-using-pnp-file-picker-in-the-sharepoint-framework-spfx-webpart/). There are many ways of doing this especially with premade components such as [PnP SPFx Controls](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/FilePicker/)